# Ajax response returning and empty line and html comment tag before json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending an ajax request and expecting to have a json response. But in my response i am having a blank line and html comments tag ( `<!-- -->` ). How can i remove this unwanted blank line and characters?

P.S: This happens when i host the website online.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "edit_row.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

php:

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $data = array();
    -----
    sql query
    ------
    while($query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $data[] = $query;
    }
    print json_encode($data);
>?
```

I am expecting the output to be something like this:

```
[{"id":"1", "asd":"dsa",...}]
```

But i am getting:

```
<!-- -->[{"id":"1", "asd":"dsa",...}]
```

Comment: `>?` is the incorrect way around. Is this a copy and paste error only?  It soulds like you have a space before the PHP opening tag perhaps

Comment: Also i am unable to find difference between expected and exact outcome you are getting

Comment: @RamRaider 
Just a copy paste error 
And I don't have any space before my php opening tags

Comment: @AlivetoDie
I am getting an additional blank space and the <!-- --> characters

Comment: Then check if you have any space/line break after any closing `?>` tag. In pure PHP-files, it's recommended that you don't close PHP-tags (just for this reason). It's easy to accidentally add white spaces.

Comment: that means in your code somewhere you outputted that stuff.Check once.Also  `?>` at the end of your file [as it recommended to handle empty line/spaces issue]

Comment: If nothing helps, you can try to manually remove the line/chars by replacing them with empty strings.

Comment: @AlivetoDie
Thanks man 
It was in an include file !!

Comment: You can always use [headers_sent()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) before you output your json to track down where previous output occurred.

Comment: `"It soulds like"` ?? that should have been `"It sounds like"`

Comment: @Ziyaad Check in your edit_row.php file, You can find  `<!-- -->` and delete that. Your bug will solve.

Comment: @Ziyaad now i will recommend you to delete this question as it's not serving any useful purpose to anybody [as it's simply TYPO mistake].Also unnecessary answers got posted. As well as down-votes happen both on answer and question as well. [BTW i am not forcing you to do so]

Answer (score 0):

if at all you are sending var id and returning blank then in ajax success call change the code.This is a temporary solution but you should retrospect the code once again in HTML.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "edit_row.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(data){
        data=data.replace("<!--","");
        data=data.replace("-->","");
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem is, but it is important to always wrap your `php/code` script around a [try and catch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) to get php errors and warnings if the is any, in you case e.g

```
<?php

try {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $data = array();
  -----
  sql query
  ------
  while($query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $data[] = $query;
  }
  print_r(json_encode($data));
}

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I also changed you php closing tag from `>?` to `?>` though I'm not sure if that's causing the problem. Also changed `print` to [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) which is better for readability of arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all the file which are includes in `edit_row.php` file and make sure `<!-- -->` not render.

Still you face the issue, can you provide `edit_row.php` code.